# Comparing scheduled time with current time in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an Apps Script snippet that calculates time and compares it with the current time. However, when the scheduled time is later than the current time, the comparison always results in "YES." I need help modifying the code to find a reliable format for the scheduled time and logically compare it with the current time. I think the issue may related to the formatting of the cell for date and time, although I tried to enforce the date and time formatting with Utilities.formatDate.

**convertToTehranTime** function stores the converted time as **scheduledTime** in desired column.

Code Snippet:

```
for (var i = 2; i <= lastRowA; i++) {
  var row = sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

  var scheduledTime = row[scheduledTimeColumnIndex];

  convertToTehranTime(i);
  var now = new Date();
  var scheduledDateTime = new Date(scheduledTime);
  scheduledDateTime = Utilities.formatDate(scheduledDateTime, "Asia/Tehran", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");

  if (scheduledDateTime <= now) {
    sheet.getRange(i, 18).setValue("YES");
  }
}
```

and this is the function of time conversion:

```
function convertToTehranTime(i) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
// Retrieve the row data using the i value
  var rowData = data[i - 1];

    var timeString = rowData[12]; // Column M
    var timeZoneOffset = 3.5 - rowData[9]; // Column J
    
     
    // Convert the time string to a Date object
    var date = parseTimeString(timeString);
    
    // Calculate the new date and time in Tehran time
    var newDate = new Date(date.getTime() + timeZoneOffset * 60 * 60 * 1000); // Convert to Tehran time
    
    // Check if the scheduled date falls on a weekend (Saturday or Sunday)
    if (newDate.getDay() === 6 || newDate.getDay() === 0) { // Saturday or Sunday
      // Increment the date to the next working day
      newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + getNextWorkingDayOffset(newDate));
    }

   
    rowData[13] = newDate; // Column N
  
    
  // Update the sheet with the new data
  sheet.getDataRange().setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for your comment. In fact I want to enforce the code to write the converted time (scheduled time) and current time in my desired format (dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm) so I have used `Utilities.formatDate` but seems that the final values are not suitable for comparison in the conditional code. in other words, it cannot compare the scheduled time and current time properly and it gives the wrong result for comparing them. suppose that the **scheduledDateTime = 20/07/2023 20:00**and current time is **now =19/07/2023 20:00** , the result of above code `if` condition is YES for these values

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, in this case, can you provide your whole script and your sample Spreadsheet? I would like to confirm your situation.

Comment: @Tanaike You can check the sheet and its script via this **[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/122DX0kkLrD7a1A3ewwlOwDA9Ft8FHLj93RbvaQ-c-sk/edit?usp=sharing)**   I want to write a reliable if conditional for comparing current time and scheduled time and also enforce the code to write the date and time in dedicated cells in **"Asia/Tehran", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"** format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vtv = new Date(sh.getRange("A1").getValue()).valueOf();
  if (vtv) {
    if (vtv < new Date().valueOf()) {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Time is in past");
    } else {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Time is in future")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I tried your code with some modifications and it worked but I have two questions: 1) is it possible to use `Utilities.formatDate` or another method in order to enforce the code to produce custom formatted date and time cell content?  2) why have you used `.valueOf()` in line 4?

Comment: You cannot compare Date() objects.  If you wish to compare numerically you need the values by using valueOf() or getTime()

Comment: Utilites.formatDate() returns a string not a date.  If you wish to format the date in a spreadsheet you can use setNumberFormat()

Comment: Thanks. Could you please modify your solution using `setNumberFormat()` for formatting the date and time like **"Asia/Tehran", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"** ?

Comment: What's keeping you from doing it?

Comment: You know, I want to store the calculated date and time of the code in this specific format "Asia/Tehran", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"  in the google sheet. how can I use `setNumberFormat()` to do that?

Comment: I don't know.  Maybe you can't.  I suspect you can thought.  I recommend trying it yourself.